# QT: Qtableview wrapping text

Tags: qt, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I am working with QtableView of Qt. I am facing one problem. I am not able to fix the content in to complete cell . In my case i have fix size of column and rows can be stretched. following is sample code

```
#include <QApplication>
#include"QStandardItemModel"
#include"QTableView"
#include"QStandardItem"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

              QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(8,3);
              QTableView * pQTableView = new QTableView();

            for(int r = 0;r<8;r++)
                    for(int c = 0; c<3; c++)
                    {
                       QModelIndex index1= model->index(r,c);

                       QVariant  value("Swaminarayan maharaj");
                        model->setData(index1, value,Qt::DisplayRole );


                       QVariant  value1( Qt::AlignCenter);

                        model->setData(index1, value1,Qt::TextAlignmentRole );

                    }

            pQTableView->resize(400,400);

        pQTableView->setModel(model);

        pQTableView->setColumnWidth(0, 100);
        pQTableView->setColumnWidth(1, 100);
        pQTableView->setColumnWidth(2, 100);
pQTableView->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

As you can see i wants each cell to have "Swaminarayan maharaj".But  Swaminarayan shold be in first line of the cell and "maharaj" in second line. Inshort each cell shold display content in two lines.

In folllowing link i found Qt::TextWordWrap but i am not able to use in my code
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/27839-For-Qt-4-6-x-how-to-auto-size-text-to-fit-in-a-specified-width

Comment: The text is show on two lines when I run your code (with the required fixes to make it actually compilable...). What are you seeing?

Comment: In mycase out put is  Swaminarayan...

Comment: Did you try to run the code as you posted it (i.e. with nothing else)?

Comment: Yes same code i am running.. is there anything to do with QT Version

Comment: You can't be running the same code - the code you posted doesn't compile. Please post the _exact_ code you're using.

Comment: i have updated the code and its compiling and running also...